# Text Align Buttons for Rich Text Fields

Tags: redactor, richtext, plugin-redactorstyles

I'm trying to add the ability to be able to align text left, right and center to my rich text fields. I have had a look into it and can only find a version which works perfect for body fields but not rich content.

The plugin I tried to use for this is here: https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras

I also looked at redactorstyles which did the same thing.

Is there possibly a way to apply this to all fields or is there another way I could go about it in redactors standard.json?

Comment: Doesnt work for me any more. Is the "alignment" plugin not available any more in the latest redactor version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per their [configuration docs](https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras#configuration), which also link to [Craft's docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs) on the subject, it looks like you'd just need to add "alignment" to the plugins portion of one of your `craft/config/redactor/` JSON config files.

i.e.

```
{
    "plugins": ["alignment"]
}
```

Then whatever config you end up modifying, you'll want to make sure that config is selected under that field's settings in Craft (Settings->Fields->Your Rich Text Field).

Comment: Just what I needed, turns out I was missing out that last step. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work as Craft does not include the Alignment plugin. P&T, please add this plugin. https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/alignment/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this issue and finds the Redactor-Extras plugin isn't working, this plugin by Doug Thwaites worked for me: https://github.com/DougThwaites/CraftRedactorFontAlignment

Comment: Welcome to Craft! There's no need for a plugin - just add `"plugins": ["alignment"],` to your Redactor config

Comment: It's that easy to tell I'm new to Craft? I don't know if that's a good sign or a bad one...